# How to understand "well formed when treated as an unevaluated operand"

Tags: c++, c++17, callable

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable), which says that[emphasis mine]:

> ```
> template <class Fn, class... ArgTypes>
> struct is_invocable;
> ```
>
> Determines whether `Fn` can be invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes....` Formally, determines whether
> `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed ***when
> treated as an unevaluated operand***, where INVOKE is the operation
> defined in Callable.

How to understand the statement in bold? What's "an unevaluated operand"?

Maybe, a simple example helps to fully understand this matter.

Comment: Relevant page from the same site: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions

Comment: @Brian I carefully read the aforementioned document, and I understand what is an an unevaluated operand now. And I think `std:is_invocable` determines whether Fn can be invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes....` Formally, determines whether `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed or not, **but i can't any relation with unevaluated operand**. What does the document intend to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to understand the statement in bold? What's "an unevaluated
> operand"?

An unevaluated operand is an operand that is not evaluated.

> Maybe, a simple example helps to fully understand this matter.

```
void g(auto) requires false;
void f(auto x) { g(x); }

static_assert(is_invocable_v<decltype(f<int>), int>);
f(0); // ill-formed
```

Considering the above example, since `is_invocable` is not evaluated, `g(x)` in `f` will not actually be invoked either, so the `static_assert` will pass.

Since `f(0)` is actually evaluated, which will fail because `g(0)` fails to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: *Since * **`f(0)` is actually evaluated** *, which will fail because g(0) fails to satisfy the constraints.* When `f(0)` is actullay evaluated? Compiling the code snippet or running the binary program?

Comment: `f(0)` is evaluated at runtime, but fails to instantiate at compile time.